# When is Overwatch set?

Tags: overwatch

I was wondering when the various events of the Overwatch timeline happen. Like the omnic crisis and the Overwatch recall. I have searched around a bit but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The game itself is set 60 years in the future, but the story really
>   starts a mere 30 years down the road.

[Link](http://blizzardwatch.com/2016/02/19/know-your-lore-overwatch-and-the-omnic-crisis/)